# Can't get handle on timer

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

Referring to these two code snippets:

```
<div id="UpdatePanel3">     
    <span id="Timer3" style="visibility:hidden;display:none;"></span>
    <select name="DropDownList1" id="DropDownList1" class="form-control" 
        size="2" onchange="navFromList(this.value);">
        <option value="12720">Blawblawblaw</option>
    </select>                                           
</div>
```

and this down below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
        $create(Sys.UI._Timer, {"enabled":true,"interval":15000,"uniqueID":"Timer3"}, null, null, $get("Timer3"));
    });
//]]>
```

I am trying to stop the timer so that the div stops refreshing. Many web sites and code blogs say the correct way to do this is:

```
var timer = $find('<%= Timer3.ClientID %>');    
timer._stopTimer();
```

But when I do this `timer` is always null.  What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have that code in a `<script>` element on a ASPX page or in a script file?

Comment: Edited OP to make more clear.

Comment: I meant the `var timer`... code actually.

Comment: Ah... the onload event handler on the same page.

Comment: I think you should be able to just do `$find('Timer3')`, but it's been a few years.

Comment: Wouldn't that bring back the span with that Id? (Yes, the timer and the span have the same name...  I didn't write it and I can't change their names... :(  )   And if `$find('Timer3')` didn't bring back the span, why not? What makes it pick the Sys.UI._Timer over the span?

Comment: I don't think it would. `$get()` would, but `$find()` is supposed to find the component with that id, not the element. Try it an see. If it doesn't work, you can try [`Sys.Application.findComponent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397522(loband).aspx).